# SQL Server Event Alerts Lack Enough Details

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, alerts

I setup SQL Server Alerts to send me emails whenever certain events (by severity) occur. Below is an example of en email I received for a "`014 - Insufficient Permission`" severity event of `Type` "`SQL Server event alert`." I looked in the Error Log as well, but no more detailed information can be found.

```
DATE/TIME:      1/9/2013 3:38:01 PM

DESCRIPTION:    Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\username'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

COMMENT:        (None)

JOB RUN:        (None)
```

I want to increase the level of detail provided in these alerts to make it easier to debug and resolve issues. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what more do you need to know? The named user failed login...

Comment: @MitchWheat For example, the Server they were trying to login to? What application were they using? Etc. In this case the user is a utility account which is using SQL Server authentication and is used for many of our applications to connect to various databases.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @mrdenny SQL Server 2005

Comment: There's not going to be anything you can really add then.  If you were using SQL 2008 or higher you could look at extended events and gather data that way.  You can put the server name in the FROM field when you configure the email.  The application they are using isn't going to be available to you.

Comment: @mrdenny That's very unfortunate. This level of error logging is completely useless to me then as it provides no means of investigation the cause of said errors. Why is virtually everything about SQL Server Administration so disappointing until 2008 and above? :(

Comment: Auditing wasn't really worried about until SOX came around which happened about 2003 or so.  By then the feature set was locked and additional auditing couldn't be added into the product.

Comment: I am not suggesting this, but since you are on SQL 2005 and don't EE as Denny said, you could create a server side trace to capture this kind of data and keep it somewhere.  There is overhead and storage issues to consider with doing this but it would get you what you need if it is important enough to spend those resources on.   Here is an example if you have not done this before:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/272/profiler-and-server-side-traces/